# CakePHP statement query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a doubt on how I should write my query on CakePHP.
Instead of using the querybuilder from CakePHP I´d like to use the statement query.
So I my query is:

```
SELECT `Post`.id, `Post`.title, COUNT(`Like`.id) AS `Posts_Liked`
FROM posts AS `Post`, likes AS `Like`
WHERE `Post`.id = `Like`.posts_id;
```

But when I send the result to the View page, I can´t get the count number when calling `$post['post']['Posts_Liked']`, so how should I call this data in the view?

Comment: Use `debug($result); die;` in the controller and see if it is what you expecting

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation result will not be added to the data array as per the [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries)

You should either use [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries) or get the data like this :

```
$post[0]['Posts_Liked']
```

you can inspect your data using

```
debug($post);
```

to see how your array is structured.

Using virtual fields you could achieve this like this:

```
$this->Post->virtualfields['Posts_liked'] = 0;
$this->Post->query('SELECT `Post`.id, `Post`.title, COUNT(`Like`.id) AS `Posts_liked` FROM posts AS `Post`, likes AS `Like` WHERE `Post`.id = `Like`.posts_id;');
```

and then get your data as per usual

```
$post['Post']['Posts_liked']
```

If you want it permanent, you should give a try to the [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count)

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a `pr($post); die();` right after making your model call, before it even gets to the view. I'm thinking it may be referenced by `$post[0]['Posts_Liked']`, since it's an aggregate function. You'll notice that CakePHP puts `SUM()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, etc. in a `$result[0]['count'];` kind of notation. Hope this helps.

CakePHP's `pr()` function is much better than `print_r`, imho.